# Can someone explain to me how this regex works? (Total novice here)

Tags: java, regex

I got this regex from a member on this site and decided to play with it till I got what I wanted.

```
"(\\d+\\.\\d$)", "$10"
```

It seems to work. My job is to convert any value like 12.3 to 12.30 or 1.0 to 1.00 and 12.33 remains the same.

Does this fit it?

Comment: that's because the second `\d` can only hold a single value, I believe--but I think it really depends on the programming language that you're using.  Try adding a `*` after the second `\d`, just before `$`.  Also, you could try googling something like `[LANG] interactive regex` and  use one of the sites listed to test out your regex expressions.  (Note, that `LANG` should be replaced by the language in question, such as 'perl').

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\d would match a single digit

`+` is quantifier which matches **1 to many** preceding characters..So,\d+ would match 1 to many digits

You can capture values in a group represented as `()` and then you can refer it back.So when you use this regex `(\d)(\d)` it captures first digit in `group 1` and the second digit in `group 2`.You can now refer back to these captured values using `$1`,`$2`..

Answer (score 0):

One or more numeric digits, followed by a period, followed by a digit and the end of the line

\d matches a single numeric digit, and the + after it means "one or more of what preceded". Then the . is escaped so its just a . , then a single digit again \d, and end of line $.

Note that in java, you need to "double escape" as in \d.